# Parentheses size around matrix

Tags: matrices, line-spacing, setspace

I would like to get 1:n matrix with `\left`, `\right` size parentheses. Default size looks not so good. Now I have

```
$\begin{pmatrix}
f_0 & \ldots & f_L
\end{pmatrix}^T$
```

The view I get

[image]

I can get the view that I want like this

```
$\left(f_0 \quad \ldots \quad f_L\right)^T$
```

[image]

but maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't look good enough? Try compiling `\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}\node[red] (a) {$\begin{pmatrix}f_0 & \ldots & f_L\end{pmatrix}^T$};\node[blue] (b) {$\left(f_0 \quad \ldots \quad f_L\right)^T$};
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}` I think `pmatrix` solution is pretty OK.

Comment: @percusse: Yes, in your sample document I can really see what I want, however, in my doc the view is not the same (see example in edited message). Is that because of other packages I use?

Comment: @Pavasaris Quite possibly!  It is best to compose a fully working (ie so that someone can cut-and-paste it and compile it without adding anything) example (preferably also minimal) so that others can see exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: You're probably using `\setspace` or another method for widening the interline space. So no: a one line "matrix" is out of the question, use the simple parentheses.

Comment: Of course, you can use `\bigl(...\bigr)` to have a bit larger parenthesis, which might look good.

Comment: I think the two images are mixed up: the first one should normally have smaller parentheses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using a package such as `setspace` or a similar method in order to widen the interline spacing, then you're out of luck.

The `array` environment uses the current baseline skip (distance between consecutive lines of text) to set itself up and the `matrix` environments provided by `amsmath` rely on `array` and this is probably why the parentheses grow in your example.

You can circumvent the problem by defining your own command:

```
\newcommand{\rowvector}[1]{%
  \begingroup\def\arraystretch{0}\begin{pmatrix}
  #1
  \end{pmatrix}\endgroup}
```

Then the input

```
$\rowvector{f_0 & \ldots & f_L}^T$
```

will work as you want.