# How to improve row vector appearance inside paragraph?

Tags: line-spacing, setspace, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parentheses size around matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57150/parentheses-size-around-matrix)

When using a row vector inside paragraph with double line spacing the output looks ugly (imo) because the brackets are too tall and much bigger than the text itself.

I tried using the package `setspace` in the middle of the paragraph to force single space, but this also breaks the line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

% Single space
Some text $ \mathbf{r} = \begin{bmatrix*} 0 & -1 & 0,5 & 0 & 0 & -\pi/18 \end{bmatrix*}^T $ then some more text.

\vspace{20pt}
% Double space
\begin{doublespace} Some text $ \mathbf{r} = \begin{bmatrix*} 0 & -1 & 0,5 & 0 & 0 & -\pi/18 \end{bmatrix*}^T $ then some more text. \end{doublespace}

% Forcing single spacing in middle of paragraph
\vspace{20pt}
\begin{doublespace} Some text in double space, \begin{singlespace} $ \mathbf{r} = \begin{bmatrix*} 0 & -1 & 0,5 & 0 & 0 & -\pi/18 \end{bmatrix*}^T $ \end{singlespace} then some more text in double space. \end{doublespace}
\end{document}
```

and this is the output

[image]

Any ideas how to improve this?

Comment: @egreg +1 for your answer to the related question, to which I added the [tag:line-spacing] and [tag:setspace] tags.

Comment: Wow, +1 for me too, but I would have never found it the way I was searching for it.